# Show dropdown menu on hover of anchor tag

Tags: html, css

I have following ul and li structure and on hover of anchor tag I want to show ul items as dropdown menu.

- What's new

  - List Item One
  - List Item One
  - List Item One
  - List Item One
  - List Item One

But I am not able to get any css code.So please help me to write the css code.

Comment: If you need assistance with the CSS code, I would firstly suggest creating a mock environment on jsfiddle.net - this would make it easier for someone to apply and test styles on your code.

Comment: what is your html structure, css structure??

Comment: Hi Pankaj - Did you manage to get what you were looking for? Did our answers help? Please remember to give us feedback and/or mark our answers as accepted. If you are still stuck, put down a comment and we'll help some more!

Answer (score 0):

I've built the structure for you on jsfiddle. As you specifically asked for the hover event on the anchor link, I have built it up for you as such.

Here's the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/mcz4u8pg/1/

And here's the code:

```css
#main {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
#main > li {
  float: left;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  margin: 10px;
}
.sub {
  display:none;
}
li > a:hover ~ .sub {
  display:block
}
.sub {
  clear:both;
  list-style:none;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}
```

```html
<ul id="main">
  <li><a href="">1</a></li>
  <li><a href="">2</a>
    <ul class="sub">
      <li>a</li>
      <li>b</li>
      <li>c</li>
      <li>d</li>
      <li>e</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href="">3</a></li>
  <li><a href="">4</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
.mainmenu li a:hover ul.submenu { display:block;}
```

Comment: Although this code may answer the question, providing
additional context regarding _why_ and/or _how_ it answers
the question would significantly improve its long-term
value.  Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation.